# How do I download an image or bitmap from an API endpoint without using ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley, okhttp

I am trying to **download** an image from an endpoint using **Volley** or **okhttp3** in android(java), there are ways to show that image in `ImageView`, is there a way I could download an image from an API endpoint, and **save** it in `assets` folder in a sub-folder named `images`. I have been at it for a while now, kind of a beginner with Volley and okhttp. It would be great if someone could help me out.

So far I have tried using ImageRequest,

```
public void getImages(String url) {
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest("url",
            response -> {

            }, 0, 0, null,
            error -> {

            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("param1", "num1");
            params.put("param2", "num2");
            return params;
        }
    };
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: No you cannot save to the assets folder as it is read only. Why not save to normal file storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments .it is not possible to modify the assets folder . consider saving it in local storage

```
 protected Uri saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap){

    ContextWrapper wrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());

    File file = wrapper.getDir("Images",MODE_PRIVATE);

    file = new File(file, System.currentTimeMillis()+"_yourFileUnique"+".jpg");

    try{
        OutputStream stream = null;
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

    }catch (IOException e) // Catch the exception
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
    return savedImageURI;
}
```

Comment: Where does that bitmap instance come from? There is no bitmap if you download an image file.